# Check all checkboxes with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, function, input, checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function set_checked {
        alert('test'); 
        $('*:checkbox').attr('checked', checked);
    }
});
```

And this html

```
<input onclick="set_checked()" value="Check all" type="button" />
```

Does not work for some reason. No alert box or nothing.

Comment: Using firebug or another javascript console can help prevent this kind of problem because they will tell you if you have syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few problems,

- missing parentheses in `set_checked` function definition
- undefined variable `checked`
- `onclick` references global function that isnt really global

With jQuery it is better to add the click event to an element with the jQuery `click` method.
Here is how to correctly do this with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // If you want to use the `set_checked` function elsewhere do this
    function set_checked() {
        $('*:checked').attr('checked', true);
    }
    $('#check_all').click(set_checked);

    // If you are only doing `set_checked` on the button press do this
    $('#check_all').click(function() {
        $('*:checked').attr('checked', true);
    });
});

<input id="check_all" value="Check all" type="button"/>
```

Comment: Did you mean `.prop` instead of `.attr`?

Comment: Yes I meant `.attr` because it was the appropriate jQuery method in 2011 but you raise a valid point that current versions of jQuery suggest using `.attr` for element attributes and `.prop` for DOM object properties. See the [jQuery `.prop` documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more info on the behavior of `.prop`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('*:checkbox').attr('checked', checked);
```

is presumably resolving as

```
$('*:checkbox').attr('checked', undefined);
```

You should have

```
$('*:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
function set_checked() {
        alert('test'); 
        $('*:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
```

You forgot the `()`

Edit: As it was said below checked must be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Make your javascript function:

```
function set_checked() {
    alert('test');
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked'); 
}
```

Your function was not defined correctly as it was missing the brackets on the name definition.

EDIT: was missing the quotes on the checked attribute as well.  Also made the selector more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating the function properly. You need to add `()` between `set_checked` and `{`.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: there's no reason to place your functions inside `$(document).ready();`, that's for things that must be run at startup.

**Update:**

I'll throw in an example of you want to do it jQuery's style all-wide.

HTML:

```
<p><input id='test' type='submit' value='Click me' onclick='checkAll();' /></p>
<p>Let's see:</p>
<ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
    <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
    <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').click(function (event) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KGBBw/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the entire example code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function set_checked {
        alert('test'); 
        $('*:checkbox').attr('checked', checked);
    }
 });
```

with:

```
function set_checked() {
    alert('test'); 
    $('*:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

As others have mentioned, you need () on your function definition, and quotes around 'checked', but you also need the function defined in global scope, so not within a jquery onready handler.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the set_checked function inside function which means that it isn't in the global scope and cannot be accessed by the input click event.